# delete files from FTP servers with linux terminal

Tags: command-line, server, ftp

I'm new here, I would like to ask a question about FTP.

I have an FTP server that contains multiple folders and there are PDF files in them. I wonder if there is a way to access this server through the terminal and delete PDF files through the terminal.

my OS is ubuntu 19.10

I use this command to download the folders

```
wget -m --user=XXXXX --password=XXXX ftp://XXXXXXX:XXXX/
```

Now I just need a command to be able to delete the PDF files from the server. :)

Comment: use Filezilla, best fit for your problem I guess.

Comment: hi friend thanks for the suggestion but it had to be on the linux terminal same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete files/folders from an FTP server, follow these steps:

1. Type `ftp` and enter to continue.
2. Type `open` and enter to continue.
3. Type  the ftp server IP address and enter to connect to ftp server.
4. If connected, type login name and enter.
5. Type user password and enter. If the username and password are valid, then you'll be in.
6. Type `help` to list all available commands that you can run on an ftp server.
7. Type `ls` to list all files and directories.
8. Type `cd <folder_name>` to get into a specified folder.
9. type `mdelete <filename>` to delete a file or multiple files or `rmdir -r <folder_name>` to delete a folder.
10. Type *y* and enter to confirm the delete.

**EDIT:**
For some security reasons, you have to type *y* everytime you want to delete a file. To avoid that, you need to run `ftp -i` in the beginning (instead of `ftp`). After that, you can delete files directly without typing *y* for every file (exp: `mdelete folder_name/*` will delete all files in folder_name).
Also, you can not delete a folder unless it is empty, so you have to delete all its content using `mdelete folder_name/*`, then run `rmdir folder_name` to delete a folder.

**Credits:**  [Mass delete files in FTP server](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2018/09/07/mass-delete-files-in-ftp-server/)

Answer (score 0):

To automate this you could use something like this.[1]

It will connect properly and everything between `<<EOF` and `EOF` will be executed.
This is quite neat for automation. I guess that's why you emphasized the need for the console, right?

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=ftp.example.com
USER=ftpuser
PASSWORD=P@ssw0rd

ftp -inv $HOST <<EOF
user $USER $PASSWORD
cd /path/to/file
    bye
EOF
```

Taken from [1]: https://blog.eduonix.com/shell-scripting/how-to-automate-ftp-transfers-in-linux-shell-scripting/